# Enviando um payload com scapy

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from scapy.all import *

ip = IP(dst = "192.168.1.1")

tcp = TCP (dport = 80, flags = "S")


raw = Raw(b"Olaa")

pkt = ip/tcp/raw

sr(pkt)

ans,unans = sr(pkt)
```

Estou aprendendo a usar o Scapy do Python. Eu não consegui entender o que é raw. Por que para enviar um payload preciso fazer `raw = Raw(b"Olaa")` ?
Também não entendi porque passar uma tupla em  `ans,unans = sr(pkt)`
Alguém poderia, por favor, esclarecer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Raw` é uma classe do arquivo `packet.py` do [Scapy](https://fossies.org/dox/scapy-2.3.1/index.html). Você pode ver o código fonte [**aqui**](https://fossies.org/dox/scapy-2.3.1/packet_8py_source.html#l01127).

```
class Raw(Packet):
     name = "Raw"
     fields_desc = [ StrField("load", "") ]
     def answers(self, other):
         return 1
         #s = str(other)
         #t = self.load
         #l = min(len(s), len(t))
         #return  s[:l] == t[:l]
     def mysummary(self):
         cs = conf.raw_summary
         if cs:
             if callable(cs):
                 return "Raw %s" % cs(self.load)
             else:
                 return "Raw %r" % self.load
         return Packet.mysummary(self)
```

A letra `b` ou `B` precedendo a *string* em Python 2 é [ignorado](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> Um prefixo `b` ou `B` é ignorado em Python 2; isso indica que o
>   literal deve tornar-se um literal de bytes em Python 3. O prefixo `u` ou `b` pode ser seguido por um prefixo `r`.

Em Python 3, segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

> (Em tradução livre)
>
> `Bytes` literais são sempre prefixados com `b` ou `B`; eles produzem uma instância do tipo [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#bytes) em vez do tipo [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str).
>   Eles só podem conter caracteres ASCII; `bytes` com um valor numérico de
>   *128* ou maior deve ser expresso com escapes.

Você deve passar as variáveis `ans` e `unans` porque a função [`sr`](https://fossies.org/dox/scapy-2.3.1/sendrecv_8py_source.html#l00304) devolve uma [*tupla*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) devolvendo pacotes e respostas e pacotes não respondidos.

Comment: estou usando python3. Falaram que no python 2 usamos: Raw("Olaa") sem b na frente. Disseram que o b é colocado no python3... É verdade?

Comment: @PaulSigonoso Sim. No Python 2 o `b` é ignorado conforme você pode ler na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Comment: O que é pkt = ip/tcp/raw ?

Comment: @PaulSigonoso Coloca em `pkt` o *ip*, informações de *porta* e o *raw*. Dê uma olhada nesse artigo sobre..: https://thepacketgeek.com/scapy-p-06-sending-and-receiving-with-scapy/

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda!